# Android - Intent to "go back" to task stack

Tags: android, navigation

The question is simple: **Is there an intent FLAG that works exactly like pressing the back button? (making the activity slide from the left)**

I need an intent to work exactly as moveTaskToBack(true) (if previous activity is in task stack).

I have tried calling `Activity A` (Main) with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, but it doesn't get it "from the stack". I think it's creating a new instance, cause if I press back, I get the (on purpose unfinished) Activity B.

*Note: I DON'T want to finish Activity B cause I need to go forward to it in some cases, without loosing the already loaded data.*

Comment: Did you found anything?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to call Activity B with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP if you want that to be on top of the stack and have A off of the stack.

If you never want Activity A to remain on the stack you can put in your manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityA"
    android:noHistory="true">
```

To go up to Activity A from your menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 switch (item.getItemId()) {
       case android.R.id.home:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
        return(true);
}

return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
```

If you are using you have to put: 
    android:launchMode="singleTask"

in manifest for your Activity B.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want A to be on stack ALWAYS. I need to bring A "back" from stack, using the UP button (even if the user pressed home, played around and came back).

Comment: Do you want to make Activity A your home button then?  You could FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP for other activities in between as well if you feel you need to.

Comment: Yes. Activity A is the main activity. I've started my question from Activity B because I need to know how to "go back" with an intent.
My test with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP is not clearing the task and I can go back to B using the hard back button (and I shouldn't)

Comment: I edited my answer to include the manifest change you have to make.